# How do I make clickonce use local files rather than download from server?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, deployment, clickonce

I did deploy my C# application with clickonce (using "yes, the application is available either online or offline") to my server via FTP. It generated the `app.publish` folder. When I run setup.exe it rather than install using files from `Application Files` folder it download from server. This is the latest software version. I thought it would download files from server where there's a most recent version and in the very first time of installation would use local files. Why it does download from server rather than using local files? how can I make it use rather the local files?

Answer (score 1):

Check with fiddler, if it really download files.
Click once shows progress bar, but actually, it just check that files (dll or other) was modified and download only changed files.